# Does concerted oxidative addition follow first-order kinetics?

Tags: transition-metals, organometallic-compounds

So my professor for organometallic chemistry described the different mechanisms for oxidative addition and in talking about the concerted mechanism he said that it had *first order kinetics*. I find this very odd as no step in the mechanism seems to involve a single reactant, so it doesn't seem like the rate-determining step could possibly be one with only one molecule.

I have included a picture of the mechanism shown on his slides. Is he correct in saying that it is first-order? Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: There isn’t really a single mechanism of oxidative addition (or may not always even be a single step). I’d depends on the oxidation state of the metal, the polarity of the ligand being inserted, the coordination geometry etc.

Comment: Did your professor say first order *overall*, or did he say first order *in metal complex reactant* ?